# AngularJS get next state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

im facing an issue and I don't know how to solve it.

The problem is that I need to go from /login to /app/settings without loggin in.

The problem is when I enter on /app It checks if its logged... how can I get the next state where im routing?

app.js

```
.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl     : "templates/menu.html",
    controller      : 'AppCtrl',
    onEnter: function($state, Auth){
        console.log($state.toState,"toState")
        if(!Auth.isLoggedIn()){
           $state.go('login');
        }
    }
  })

.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl     : "templates/session/login.html",
    controller      : 'SessionCtrl'
  })
```

login.html:

```
<button ui-sref="app.settings({toState: 'app.config'})" class="button icon ion-ios-information-outline"></button>
```

how can I get app.settings route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a hidden parameter that auth is optional.

```
.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl     : "templates/menu.html",
    controller      : 'AppCtrl',
    params: {
        ignore: false
    },
    onEnter: function($state, $stateParams, Auth){
        if(!$stateParams.ignore && !Auth.isLoggedIn()){
           $state.go('login');
        }
      }
  })
```

Then you set this hidden param

```
<button ui-sref="app.settings({toState: 'app.config'})" ui-sref-opts="{ignore:true}" class="button icon ion-ios-information-outline"></button>
```

Comment: Was writing exactly the same answer, just gave an other name to the param. This solution is probably the cleanest way to achieve that :)

Comment: I always get ignore = false :S

Comment: Try this : ui-sref="app.settings({toState: 'app.config', ignore:true})"